# Qt three ComboBoxes for a date

Tags: qt, date, combobox

I have been looking around Google and Stackoverflow, but I have yet to find out if there is any simple solution to auto-filling three comboboxes to represent a correct date (like YYYY-MM-DD). I would presume it would be related to QCalendarWidget. Any ideas?

I want to be able to scroll through current time to dates from X years ago, it shouldn't have non-existant dates like February 29, 2011. Not sure if this is asking for too much.

Comment: For that you have to add those dates manually to combo boxes.Use some simple logic in loop. I don't think there is too much to be done in implementing it this way

Comment: Why would you need three combo-boxes with identical content? I would recommend using QDateEdit instead of QComboBox

Comment: One box is YYYY, one is MM, one is DD. I will look into QDateEdit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now i get what's your idea.

The answer is simple. Make three combo boxes: Day (1 - 31), Month (1 - 12) and Year (i.e. 1999 - 2012). Create "OK" button. No ultra-logic is needed.

After button being pressed just validate the date by creating QDate object with three numbers given by user and calling QDate::isValid(). If it isn't, create some warning prompt and ask user to change something in input.

The best way to validate the data entered by user is to override QDialog::done() method.

```
void Dialog::done(int r)
{
    if(r == QDialog::Accepted) {
        QDate date; 
        //Create QDate from comboboxes' values
        ...
        if(!date.isValid()) { 
            //Some warning to user.
            return;
        }
    }
    QDialog::done(r);
}
```

Comment: Just my personal opinion: An alternative way would be to make the available days dependent from the month currently being selected, so if you select "February", you can only select the days 1..28 or 29, depending on the year. But this would be not as easy to use as you might think, because if you start selecting the day (while the month is at "February"), you might not be able to select the day you want to, so you would *have to start with the year*, then the month and finally the day. This will restrict the user.

Answer (score 1):

```
int X = 2;
QDate date = QDate::currentDate(), lastDate = date.addYears(-X);
for(; date > lastDate; date = date.addDays(-1))
    ui->comboBox->addItem(date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood the question... I thought author expects three comboboxes like this one. Now i see he meant one for day, one for month and one for year...